# Output Date format with ORMLite

Tags: android, ormlite

I'm adding ORMLite to an existing project, so I already have a database, this is my class:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "demandes")
public class Demandes {


    public static final String TABLE_DEMANDES = "demandes";

    public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_XML_SENDLEAD = "xmlSendLead";
    public static final String KEY_STATUTENVOIE_SENDLEAD = "statutEnvoieSendLead";
    public static final String KEY_DATEENVOIE_SENDLEAD = "dateEnvoieSendLead";
    public static final String KEY_CONTACTWEBID = "contactWebId";
    public static final String KEY_XML_SIMULATION = "xmlSimulation";
    public static final String KEY_STATUTENVOIE_SIMULATION = "statutEnvoieSimulation";
    public static final String KEY_DATEENVOIE_SIMULATION = "dateEnvoieSimulation";

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, allowGeneratedIdInsert = true,columnName = KEY_ID)
    private int id;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = KEY_XML_SENDLEAD)
    private String xmlSendLead;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = KEY_STATUTENVOIE_SENDLEAD)
    private int statutEnvoieSendLead;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = KEY_DATEENVOIE_SENDLEAD, dataType = DataType.DATE_STRING, format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private Date dateEnvoieSendLead;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = KEY_CONTACTWEBID)
    private int contactWebId;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = KEY_XML_SIMULATION)
    private String xmlSimulation;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = KEY_STATUTENVOIE_SIMULATION)
    private int statutEnvoieSimulation;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = KEY_DATEENVOIE_SIMULATION, dataType = DataType.DATE_STRING, format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private Date dateEnvoieSimulation;


    public Demandes() {
    }

    public Demandes(String xmlSendLead, int statutEnvoieSendLead, Date dateEnvoieSendLead, int contactWebId, String xmlSimulation, int statutEnvoieSimulation, Date dateEnvoieSimulation) {
        this.xmlSendLead = xmlSendLead;
        this.statutEnvoieSendLead = statutEnvoieSendLead;
        this.dateEnvoieSendLead = dateEnvoieSendLead;
        this.contactWebId = contactWebId;
        this.xmlSimulation = xmlSimulation;
        this.statutEnvoieSimulation = statutEnvoieSimulation;
        this.dateEnvoieSimulation = dateEnvoieSimulation;
    }

    public Demandes(int id, String xmlSendLead, int statutEnvoieSendLead, Date dateEnvoieSendLead, int contactWebId, String xmlSimulation, int statutEnvoieSimulation, Date dateEnvoieSimulation) {
        this.id = id;
        this.xmlSendLead = xmlSendLead;
        this.statutEnvoieSendLead = statutEnvoieSendLead;
        this.dateEnvoieSendLead = dateEnvoieSendLead;
        this.contactWebId = contactWebId;
        this.xmlSimulation = xmlSimulation;
        this.statutEnvoieSimulation = statutEnvoieSimulation;
        this.dateEnvoieSimulation = dateEnvoieSimulation;
    }

    public Date getDateEnvoieSimulation() {
        return dateEnvoieSimulation;
    }

    public void setDateEnvoieSimulation(Date dateEnvoieSimulation) {
        this.dateEnvoieSimulation = dateEnvoieSimulation;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getXmlSendLead() {
        return xmlSendLead;
    }

    public void setXmlSendLead(String xmlSendLead) {
        this.xmlSendLead = xmlSendLead;
    }

    public int getStatutEnvoieSendLead() {
        return statutEnvoieSendLead;
    }

    public void setStatutEnvoieSendLead(int statutEnvoieSendLead) {
        this.statutEnvoieSendLead = statutEnvoieSendLead;
    }

    public Date getDateEnvoieSendLead() {
        return dateEnvoieSendLead;
    }

    public void setDateEnvoieSendLead(Date dateEnvoieSendLead) {
        this.dateEnvoieSendLead = dateEnvoieSendLead;
    }

    public int getContactWebId() {
        return contactWebId;
    }

    public void setContactWebId(int contactWebId) {
        this.contactWebId = contactWebId;
    }

    public String getXmlSimulation() {
        return xmlSimulation;
    }

    public void setXmlSimulation(String xmlSimulation) {
        this.xmlSimulation = xmlSimulation;
    }

    public int getStatutEnvoieSimulation() {
        return statutEnvoieSimulation;
    }

    public void setStatutEnvoieSimulation(int statutEnvoieSimulation) {
        this.statutEnvoieSimulation = statutEnvoieSimulation;
    }
}
```

My auto incremented primary key id looks working, my date too, because my old data was successfully retrieved. But when I'm doing a print the Date is formatted like that:

Mon Feb 06 16:03:57 GMT+01:00 2017

How I print:

```
    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

    Dao<Demandes, Integer> demandesDao = null;
    try {
        demandesDao = db.getDemandesDao();
        final List<Demandes> demandes = demandesDao.queryForAll();

        System.out.println(demandes);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

that is a unique format in ORMLite ?